# Change Background Color based on InnerHtml in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to change the background of the div based on the InnerHtml. For example: if it is 10 or above, then the color is white.
home.html

```
<template>
<div id="value">5</div>
</template>
```

home.js

```
export class Home{
}
```

Comment: if you are already running aurelia, chances are that this value is generated by a binding. if so - you should create another binding for a `class` based on the same value (using a value-converter)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div css="background-color: getColor(colorElement.innerText)" element.ref="colorElement">5</div>

getColor(text) {
  const num = Number(text);
  return isNaN(num) ? 'white' : `hsl(0,0,${Math.min(Math.max(num 0), 10)}0%`;
}
```